# Dumping a live filesystem

Tags: linux, rsync, dump

I've managed to root a device and I'd like to dump it's entire filesystem in order to analyze and reverse engineer it.

This device claims to be `Linux 2.6.31 mips GNU/Linux`. The way I can access the shell interface is via network, by simply telneting to a port.

How can I dump it's entire filesystem outside the device?

## Things I tried

- DD: Kind of out of the question, `df -h` says that the filesystem is 48% used and a `dd` image would take that to 98%, potentially making it run out of space and bricking it?
- Rsync: This one seems the best option, but AFAIK, rsync uses ssh internally, but there's no ssh to this device, you just open a port to it and it drops you to a shell. Parameters like `root@192.168.1.1:23:/` simply seem to ignore the port (`ssh: connect to host 192.168.3.10 port 22: Connection refused`). `rsync` binary is not present in the device.

## Things to consider

- Filesystem should remain exactly the same, meaning that even symlinks should still point to where they point right now.

Comment: I believe rsync needs to be installed on the rooted device so even if you had SSH access, have you checked that rsync is installed?

Comment: How minimal is the environment on the device? Is it only busybox, or do you have access to "grown-up" tools like `bash` (the real thing), `nc` (or equivalent), a scripting interpreter or a compiler?

Comment: Looks like many versions of BusyBox include `nc`, does your device have it?

Comment: Rsync is not installed, it's busybox based but `nc` is available. busybox version is 1.20.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get the data out over the network is to pipe them through a TCP connection using `nc`. Depending on how exact a clone you want, "the data" here may mean either of the following:

- The entire block device (a complete block-level image of the filesystem): `cat /dev/sda |` or `cat /dev/mtdblocksomething |` (Yes, this is a useless use of cat, used here just for consistency with the other option. Feel free to replace it with `< /dev/sda`.)
- Just the files/directories/links/etc.: `tar -c / |` (possibly with `--one-file-system`)

What comes after the pipe depends on whether you can make TCP connections from the device to your machine or vice versa. For example:

- `nc -l -p someport > deviceimage.tar` on your machine
- `tar -c / | nc yourmachine someport` on the device

If you can only make connections to the device but not from it, just swap the `nc -l` and `nc` around.

Note that cloning a running system like this without first quiescing the filesystem may get you an inconsistent snapshot if any writes occur while your clone is underway. This may be worse when cloning the whole block device (the inconsistency may corrupt the filesystem in your clone). If the device is somewhat busy, consider stopping (`kill -STOP`) whatever you can.

Comment: Excellent, just what I needed. Tar is erroring out with "short read" when going thorugh the `sys` folder but I guess that should be another question! Thanks!

Comment: @444A49 That's expected, `/proc` and `/sys` are both in-kernel virtual filesystems that you simply can't clone. `--one-file-system` would have helped here (unless the device uses multiple physical filesystems to store its data).